# Why when i check the internet connection in android i get true value?

Tags: android

I'm beginner in android and want to write simple application to check phone connect to internet?
add this permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

and write this code:

```
boolean check_net=isNetworkConnected();
```

and this method:

```
private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(testSendWithFood.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }
```

but always return true value to me!,i disconnect internet but so return true!,why?

Comment: try to call it as... `Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE` instead of `testSendWithFood.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE`.

Comment: Keep in mind that those methods both IOS or Android tend to return true when its connected to a network, but that does not necessary means that you are connected to internet!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
if (ConnectivityDetector.IS_INTERNET_AVAILABLE(MainActivity.this)) {
    // Do your stuff
} else {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No internet connection available.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**ConnectivityDetector .java**

```
public class ConnectivityDetector {

    public static boolean IS_INTERNET_AVAILABLE(Context context){
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          if (connectivity != null) 
          {
              NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
              if (info != null) 
                  for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) 
                      if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                      {
                          return true;
                      }

          }
          return false;
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

The above permission will be needed to check the internet function in android.

Comment: How this is possible?

Comment: Just because in my each project I have implemented this code and it works fine for me, why it doesn't work for you?

Comment: what is EmergencyRequestActivity.this?if your activity name,so what MainActivity.this in Toast?

Comment: my friend your code correct,i run in android emulator,but when send apk on my phone ,your code work,thanks and excuse me.

Comment: I have edited my code, this is just an activity name you should pass over there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static boolean isInternetAvailable(Context ctx) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()
            && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
            && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In context pass your current application context and In **AndroidManifest.xml** file give bellow permissions

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```